# How to host datetimepicker in DataGridView control in C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void showdate(DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dateTimePicker1.Size = vacation_transDataGridView.CurrentCell.Size;
    dateTimePicker1.Top = vacation_transDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Top + vacation_transDataGridView.Top;
    dateTimePicker1.Left = vacation_transDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Left + vacation_transDataGridView.Left;

    if (!(object.Equals(Convert.ToString(vacation_transDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value),"")))
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(vacation_transDataGridView.CurrentCell.Value);
        //dateTimePicker1.Visible = false;
    }

    dateTimePicker1.Visible = true;
}
```

This code in dgv cell_click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example of exactly this thing on MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there isn't such a Cell or Column Type you can use (as far as i know). But Microsoft provides [an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730881.aspx) on how to get a NumericUpDown (that also doesn't exist) into a DataGridView.

Maybe you can adopt this example to get your [DateTimePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx) into a DataGridView.

Comment: If you found another solution you should post it here (if it is a real answer to your question) or just delete your question.

Comment: i am found solution says you can in dgv_cellclick event call datetimepicker with the same size and location of the cell whats your opnion for this

Comment: dateTimePicker1.Size = vacation_transDataGridView.CurrentCell.Size; dateTimePicker1.Top = vacation_transDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Top + vacation_transDataGridView.Top; dateTimePicker1.Left = vacation_transDataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true).Left + vacation_transDataGridView.Left;

Comment: @shmandor: Well that's a fast and hacky way to solve your problem, but if it works as you expected, than it's okay. Maybe you can edit your question and add your code below it. Thus making it more easily to read than in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void dgtest_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
         dtp = new DateTimePicker();
        dgtest.Controls.Add(dtp);
        dtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        Rectangle Rectangle = dgtest.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
        dtp.Size = new Size(Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
        dtp.Location = new Point(Rectangle.X, Rectangle.Y);
        dtp.CloseUp += new EventHandler(dtp_CloseUp);
        dtp.TextChanged += new EventHandler(dtp_OnTextChange);
        dtp.Visible = true;
    }
}

private void dtp_OnTextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dgtest.CurrentCell.Value = dtp.Text.ToString();
}

void dtp_CloseUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    dtp.Visible = false;
}
```