# Add datetime picker control to single rows in a Datagridview - C# Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, datagridview

I have a DataGridview with 1 single column and 5 rows in a C# windows form.
How can I add a datetime control only to the rows 2 and 4?

```
// Create a new DateTimePicker control
DateTimePicker dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker();
dateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;

// Create a DataGridViewComboBoxCell
DataGridViewComboBoxCell comboBoxCell = new DataGridViewComboBoxCell();

// Add the DateTimePicker control to the ComboBox cell
comboBoxCell.Value = dateTimePicker;

// Set the ComboBox cell to the specific row and column
dataGridView1.Rows[1].Cells[1] = comboBoxCell;
dataGridView1.Rows[3].Cells[1] = comboBoxCell;
```

Comment: That's a peculiar requirement. A Column should expose the same Type of data. Why would you have a DateTimePicker in just some Cells? Do you actually have an underlying source of data? -- Are you sure you need a DataGridView? Maybe a TableLayoutPanel as container is much easier to handle in this case.

Comment: The reason is because I'm using a dynamic datagridview as form input. and some cells from the same column are simple text,  some combo boxes  or calendars (dateTimePicker).

Comment: @Jimi Yes I have an underlying data source and in my particular case, TableLaoutPanel was not an option. I solve my problem with R_V solution :)

Comment: You'll find out (sooner or later) that the answer here does provide a viable solution. These are the correct ways: with a DateTimePicker: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells) and with a NumericUpDown [Build a Custom NumericUpDown Cell and Column for the DataGridView Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa730881(v=vs.80))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at this code that does what you are looking for. Upon clicking a cell, based on the RowIndex you can decide whether to display the datetime control.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DateTimePicker cellDtp;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                DataGridViewCell NewCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
                NewCell.Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                DataGridViewRow NewRow = new DataGridViewRow();
                NewRow.Cells.Add(NewCell);
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add(NewRow);
            }
        }
        
        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            //To check if this is 2nd or 4th Row
            if (e.RowIndex == 1 || e.RowIndex == 3)
            {
                cellDtp = new DateTimePicker();
                dataGridView1.Controls.Add(cellDtp);
                cellDtp.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                Rectangle Rectangle = dataGridView1.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, true);
                cellDtp.Size = new Size(Rectangle.Width, Rectangle.Height);
                cellDtp.Location = new Point(Rectangle.X, Rectangle.Y);
                cellDtp.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[As demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45986598/9573265)